How to disable the android virtual keyboard display after closing a child QDialog containing a QTextEdit?
I'm developing a program for android. I'm trying to display a child window containing a QTextEdit input field into which text must be entered using the virtual keyboard. This step works correctly - when the input field gains focus, the virtual keyboard is displayed and closed with a down arrow. After closing a child dialog with the Back button, the virtual keyboard is again displayed on top of the parent window.
This is a simplified example that replicates the problem.
This is the code for the parent window:
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout * mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);

    QPushButton * pTextDlgButton = new QPushButton("Text dlg",this);
    connect(pTextDlgButton , SIGNAL(clicked()) , this , SLOT(OnTextDlgPress()));
    mainLayout->addWidget(pTextDlgButton);
}

Dialog::~Dialog() {}


void Dialog::OnTextDlgPress()
{
    QTextDlg dlg;
    dlg.exec();
}

This is the code for the child window:
QTextDlg::QTextDlg()
{
    QVBoxLayout * mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(mainLayout);

    QTextEdit * pTextEdit=new QTextEdit();

    mainLayout->addWidget(pTextEdit);
}

I tried to transfer focus to another element in the child dialog destructor. I tried explicitly closing the keyboard after exec() qApp->inputMethod()->hide(). I tried overriding the Back button click handler.

It may be a bug, possibly related to QTBUG-96560 (the change may have caused a regression). What Qt/Android version? Also, does this happen with a physical device or through emulation? You may consider doing some research in the Qt bug tracker and eventually file a report.

I tried Qt version 6.2.2 and android 11,12 and 13 versions.

The following event handler helped me:
bool Dialog::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        if(((QKeyEvent *)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Back)
        {
            accept();
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        if(((QKeyEvent *)event)->key() == Qt::Key_Return)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QDialog::event(event);
}

